# joining non-repeated lines in a one line - python

Tags: python, database, string, function

I seek some tips for a small but confusing data:

```
P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=0000025456
P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=0000438090
P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=0000438071
P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=00438072
P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=011423689
P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=002655525
```

In this data, only non-repeated values are present in the last col. What I want is  to simplify this data with a script/function to join these values in the same line as follow:

```
P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=0000025456, 0000438071,0000438090, 002655525, 011423689, 00438072
```

Comment: Try reading in the data line by line and split on '='.  Then append the number you want to a list.  Finally, read through the list and make your string.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = ''' P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=0000025456
P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=0000438090
P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=0000438071
P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=00438072
P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=011423689
P2  Chain   161771  642 ID=002655525'''

ids = [] # We will store the ids here
for line in text.splitlines(): # break the text block into lines and iterate over them
    split_line = line.split('=') # break the line into two pieces, before and after the '='
    id = split_line[1] # set id to be the part after '=', ie: the ID
    ids.append(id)

print ('P2 Chain 161771 642 ID=' + str(ids))
```

Output:

```
P2 Chain 161771 642 ID=['0000025456', '0000438090', '0000438071', '00438072', '011423689', '002655525']
```